# createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord requires BLUETOOTH_ADMIN?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-permissions

Are there any circumstances (including any known bug in Android 4.2) that might cause `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` to throw:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission: Neither user 10043 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothSocket$Stub$Proxy.initSocket(IBluetoothSocket.java:230)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.<init>(BluetoothSocket.java:225)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BluetoothDevice.java:948)
```

`createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29) to require only the `BLUETOOTH` permission, and not the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission. That seems reasonable.

My app only has the `BLUETOOTH` permission, and I've never seen it crash myself. But today I received one crash report from an Xperia C (C2305) running Android 4.2 with the above stack trace.

What would a reasonable course of action be here? As I'm reluctant to add more permissions, I'd probably have to catch the `SecurityException` and report it to the user as a connection failure.

Comment: If you want that part of your app to work on that device, you'll need to request the permission.  Otherwise just what you suggested will avoid the crash, but that functionality would never work.

Comment: @gabe createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord is documented to NOT require the _ADMIN permission, and it works for everyone else who has tried it. I do not understand why the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission should be required, I'm not discovering or pairing, I'm just connecting.

Comment: Apparently on that phone it does.  It may be misconfigured on accident or it may be a purposeful change that the OEM made.  Either way, that phone won't connect without that permission.

Comment: FYI-  although there's not a lot of chatter because its not a popular model, you aren't the only one who's seen this-  its been reported on Arduino forums.

Comment: @GabeSechan Interesting... do you have a link to that forum? I think that would constitute an answer to my question.

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-control-arduino-board-using-an-android-phone-a/6/?lang=de is one report (midway through comments).  User just decided to switch phones.  I had found one or two others, but having trouble finding them again-  search results are poisoned by ads for the phone.

Comment: I have the same behavior with Fly IO440